# WHERE Statement in VB.NET

Tags: mysql, .net, database, vb.net

For a school assignment I need to name computer based on their MAC-Adress. I have a mySQL table with two columns Mac-Adress and Computername. I want to use the computer's mac adress via following code, which works.

Declaration of the globals

> Public connStr As String = "Database=Mac;" & _
>                       "Data Source=localhost;" & _
>                       "User Id=root;Password="
>       Public mac_adress As String

Getting the Mac Adress

> Public Sub MacAdres()
>           Dim nic As NetworkInterface = Nothing
>
> ```
>     For Each nic In NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces
>         mac_adress = nic.GetPhysicalAddress.ToString
>     Next
> End Sub
> ```

However, when I want to create the WHERE statement, I get an error. I'm using the following code for the WHERE statement.

> ```
> Public Sub retriveData()
>     Try
>         Dim query As String = "SELECT * FROM 'mactable' WHERE 'Mac-adres' = '" & mac_adress & "'"
>         Dim connection As New MySqlConnection(connStr)
>         Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(query, connection)
>
>         connection.Open()
>
>         Dim reader As MySqlDataReader
>         reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
>
>         While reader.Read()
>             MessageBox.Show(reader.GetString(1))
>         End While
>
>         reader.Close()
>         connection.Close()
>     Catch ex As Exception
>         Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
>     End Try
> End Sub
> ```

What am I doing wrong?

> A first chance exception of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' occurred in >MySql.Data.dll

Comment: Have you tried running that query directly on Mysql? Besides removing the quotes on the fields, What does ex.Message prints? And please, post the table schema.

Answer (score 0):

I think you dont need the quotes on the tablename or the field names, and possibly remove the hyphen.

```
Dim query As String = "SELECT * FROM mactable WHERE MacAdres = '" & mac_adress & "'"
```

Comment: Nope didn't do anything. :/

Comment: Hmm.  I've seen some examples of MySQL with the quotes in there around the table names - but they're not "proper" quotes - they're the ones found beneath the tilde (~) character, above the `tab` key (and, incidentally, the ones StackOverflow uses to mark inline code blocks in comments).

Comment: @nielsvermaut what happens when you fully qualify the table name and field names in your query? like "Mac.mactable" for  the table and "Mac.mactable.Mac-adres" for the field name?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by using these: "`" instead of these '. Thats rather peculiar, but it solved it.